# Existence of prime number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If '$p$' is a prime number greater than $2$ then there exists at least one other prime, say '$q$', such that $q \gt p$ and $q \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: Theorem holds for $p=2$ as well.

Comment: Ya sure it's my mistake.

Comment: Can you give a general proof?

Comment: The condition that $q>p$ is redundant since any prime congruent to $1\pmod p$ is necessarily $>p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Comment: (In fact, this shows that there are infinitely many such primes)

Answer (score 2):

This follow from Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic
progressions, but has a more elementary proof.

For a prime $p$, and any positive integer $n$, all prime factors of
$$\frac{(pn)^p-1}{pn-1}$$
satisfy $q\equiv 1\pmod p$. To prove this (i) prove $q\ne p$, (ii) $pn$
has multiplicative order $p$ modulo $q$, (iii) $p\mid(q-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

An approach which doesn't require Dirichlet:

Let $n=2^p-1$, and $q$ be a prime factor of $n$. Then $2^p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ which means $q-1$ is divisible by $p$, or $q\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Comment: But what can you say if n is not of the form (2^p)-1 ?

Comment: @user407986 Many things can be said, but they are irrelevant for this answer.

Comment: What do you mean, @user407986? I've shown $q$ exists. What do other values of $n$ have to do with it?

Comment: I am assuming that let you consider any type of n. But how can you say q-1 is divisible by p?

Comment: Because if $2^p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ then $2$ is of order $p$ or order $1$ modulo $q$. Since it can't be order $1$, this means that $p$ must divide $q-1$.